# Issue while trying to populate the dropdown

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

**Error Details**

> Property or method "chatusers" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

**Component - 1**

```
<template lang="html">
    <div>
        <select name="User_ID" class = "form-control">
            <option value="-1">Please select User</option>
            <option v-for="chatuser in chatusers" v-bind:value="chatuser.User_ID">
               {{ chatuser.UserName }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

**Code in Blade**

```
<chat-composer :chatusers="chatusers"></chat-composer>
```

**app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        chatusers: []
    },
    created() {
        axios.post("some url").then(response => {
            if(response.Status) {
                this.chatusers= response.data.Data;
            }
            else {
                this.chatusers= [];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add props into your `Component 1`

Do this inside of `<script>`

```js
export default {
  props: ['chatUsers']
}
```

Of course, add other stuff which is relevant to your context inside the `<script>` tag too.